# Filter objects based on key value pair

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a json object as such

```
  {
      "value": "0",
      "minute": "2019-04-16T01:48",
      "action": "verb",
      "label": "noun",
      "id": "appid1"
  },
  {
      "value": "7",
      "minute": "2019-04-16T01:49",
      "action": "verb",
      "label": "noun",
      "id": "appid1"
  },
  {
      "value": "18",
      "minute": "2019-04-16T01:50",
      "action": "verb",
      "label": "noun",
      "id": "appid1"
  },
  {
      "value": "0",
      "minute": "2019-04-16T01:31",
      "action": "verb",
      "label": "noun",
      "id": "appid2"
  },
  {
      "value": "19",
      "minute": "2019-04-16T01:51",
      "action": "verb",
      "label": "noun",
      "id": "appid2"
  },
  {
      "value": "19",
      "minute": "2019-04-16T01:52",
      "action": "verb",
      "label": "noun",
      "id": "appid2"
  },
  {
      "value": "19",
      "minute": "2019-04-16T01:53",
      "action": "verb",
      "label": "noun",
      "id": "appid1"
  },
  {
      "value": "18",
      "minute": "2019-04-16T01:54",
      "action": "verb",
      "label": "noun",
      "id": "appid1"
  },
  {
      "value": "17",
      "minute": "2019-04-16T01:55",
      "action": "verb",
      "label": "noun",
      "id": "appid1"
  }
```

What I would like to have is to create three buckets (A, B, C). Bucket A has the first three `appid1` objects while bucket B has the `appid2` objects while bucket C has the third and final set of `appid1` objects.

I have tried doing something like this

```
let startIndex = 0;
let endIndex = -1;

let currentAppID = "appid1"
        data.forEach((d, index)=> {
            if(d["label"] === 'noun' && d["id"]=== currentGameId && d["action"]==="verb") {
                startIndex = index
            }

            if(d["label"] === 'noun' && d["id"]!== currentGameId && d["event.action"]==="verb") {
                endIndex = index
            }
        })

 let bucketItems = data.slice(startIndex,endIndex)
```

but this code is totally giving me absurd results. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the array and check if the `last` object and the actual object `o` has the same `id`, otherwise add a new group.

```js
var data = [{ value: "0", minute: "2019-04-16T01:48", action: "verb", label: "noun", id: "appid1" }, { value: "7", minute: "2019-04-16T01:49", action: "verb", label: "noun", id: "appid1" }, { value: "18", minute: "2019-04-16T01:50", action: "verb", label: "noun", id: "appid1" }, { value: "0", minute: "2019-04-16T01:31", action: "verb", label: "noun", id: "appid2" }, { value: "19", minute: "2019-04-16T01:51", action: "verb", label: "noun", id: "appid2" }, { value: "19", minute: "2019-04-16T01:52", action: "verb", label: "noun", id: "appid2" }, { value: "19", minute: "2019-04-16T01:53", action: "verb", label: "noun", id: "appid1" }, { value: "18", minute: "2019-04-16T01:54", action: "verb", label: "noun", id: "appid1" }, { value: "17", minute: "2019-04-16T01:55", action: "verb", label: "noun", id: "appid1" }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o, i, { [i - 1]: last }) => {
        if (!last || o.id !== last.id) r.push([]);
        r[r.length - 1].push(o);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You are GodSend . Thank you so much. I will mark your answer as such in another 1 minute.. With Regards - Gagan

Comment: Can you explain this line `{ [i - 1]: last }` please ? usually the last argument is the array we started with that's what i get when i log `argument[3]` although it looks like object destructing but i don't understand how it is working.

Comment: it is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with a [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and a renaming of a property. it takes the original array and takes a destructuring by taking an index value as computed property and while this propery has a number, it can not be taken. so a reaming is needed to get the predecessor of the actual item of the array.